# Multiple Row Sum, not sum of multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with tasks and projects and users, each user does a task for a project. now I want to get the sum of time spent for each task for each project,

```
Project   Task   Time(hrs)
Proj1     coding  2
Proj2     coding  3
Proj1     design  3
Proj2     design  2
```

Is there a way to do that in mySQL?

Comment: I think you need the GROUP BY .. WITH ROLLUP . Here is some link about that: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just group by both project and task

```
select project, 
       task, 
       sum(time) 
  from myTable 
 group by project, 
          task
```

Comment: NP, welcome to SO. You should mark one answer as "correct" if you think it is correct. It helps other users to find answers to there questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT Task, sum(TaskTime) from Tasks group by Task
```

but probably I didn't get the question right (seems tooo simple ...)

NB: a Column can not have the name `Time` since that's a reserved word at least in MySql

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

```
SELECT  Project,
        Task,
        SUM(Time) TotalTime
FROM    YourTable
GROUP BY    Project,
            Task
```